# Thermoelectric effect

Tags: thermodynamics, applied-physics, thermoelectricity

Hey just learned about this [thermoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect) in physics class,

I was wondering why it is not used more often in the form of a thermoelectric generator in practical industrial applications. Would seem like a pretty nifty heat recycling device. Idk thought it was strange. Why isnt it used for these applications?

Comment: They are extremely inefficient. Typically under 1%

Comment: Generators exist. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator

Comment: Woah under 1%!? THATS RIDICULOUS!!!!

Comment: RC_23 you got 5K reputation I bet you could make a better thermoelectric generator Than that in your sleep.

Answer (score 1):

It has been- in circumstances where its inefficiency does not matter.

Thermoelectric generators were constructed in Soviet Russia to fit on over the glass chimney of a kerosene lamp, so as to power up a simple vacuum-tube radio in regions of the USSR with kerosene lamps but without electricity.

Thermoelectric generators were also used in a variety of unmanned space probes to furnish electric power from the heat given off by radioactive decay. The Soviet spy satellite Cosmos 954 contained a thermoelectric generator powered by a fission reactor; when its orbit unexpectedly decayed and it re-entered the atmosphere over northern Canada, the uranium in the reactor core disintegrated and contaminated the impact site. The Soviets (again) also used the same sort of thermoelectric generators driven by radioactive decay to power up surveillance devices that they air-dropped into remote parts of the world to keep an eye on things.

Answer (score -1):

Thermoelectric generators can be used (and are used) in situations where power output needs are low. Main problem with them is that typical thermoelectric materials which generates thermocurrent usually operates just at the order $\mu V/K$, check [seebeck coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient). If you take for example Selenium,- it can generate $\approx 1 mV/K$, so if you want let's say to get just $5V$ output, then you must be sure that temperature difference will be $\Delta T = 5000K$,- about the temperature of Sun photosphere !

So with thermoelectric generators you can either power-up low power devices, such as hand watches, light diode bulbs, OR if you need a bit more power - then you need to exploit greater temperatures such as in a nuclear reactor active zone, then maybe you will power a couple of electronic devices, but still not very effective.

Comment: Anybody who ghosted -1, will explain motives ?